# Using App Insights datasets in Power BI Pro with multiple environments

Tags: powerbi, azure-application-insights

I'm using Power BI Pro in Azure to create reports (bar charts) for Application Insights metrics. I embed the reports in my ASP.NET Core (Razor) web pages. In Azure Portal \ Application Insights \ Logs then I create a query and then select Export | Power BI (New dataset) which opens Power BI Pro in another tab and I can create reports.

Sometimes I need to edit the query slightly but I can't see it in Azure anywhere. I have to create a new dataset and create all of the reports again. Also we have multiple environments within our Azure tenant (Development, QAT, UAT) and I need to be able to copy each report to the other environments and just change the dataset location to use the App Insights instance for that environment.

My questions:

1. How do I edit the query to make small changes? I can't see the query in Azure.
2. How do I copy a report from Development to QAT (Same workspace in Power BI) and change the QAT dataset location to refer to the QAT App Insights instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the AppInsights environment a [Power Query Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-query-parameters) and you can set it on the Dataset in the portal.

Or use [Deployment Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-process).